# Delay and group notifications

Tags: notifications

I would like to be able to reduce the number of times my phone interrupts me while I am working, without significantly decreasing my responsiveness. I have a few ideas for how to do this, but I haven't found a way to actually implement any of them.

1. Only receive notifications every N minutes. For N=10, at 2:00 I would get a few notifications. Then at 2:10, I would get the next set of notifications.
2. When my phone receives a notification, check when the last notification was delivered. If it was less than N minutes prior, wait until N minutes has elapsed then deliver all the notifications received in that time. This is the ideal solution, in my mind.

One suggestion (mentioned at [Delay notifications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88854/delay-notifications?newreg=08b04792d2454e92a71dc8e559232840)) handles silencing messages delivered at nearly the same time, but it doesn't alert the user about the second notification after the time has passed. It essentially just silences the phone for 1 minute after receiving a notification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delay notifications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88854/delay-notifications)

Comment: @willlma Clearly not, else I wouldn't have mentioned it in my question.