# Is there a way to stagger notificaton sounds?

Tags: notifications

Sometimes people send you messages line per line, sometimes there's bunch of emails or photos forwarded or maybe just couple of email in a row. There's no need for me to hear each of the 15 beeps in a minute individually and I would love to able to stagger notification sounds to limit them to say 1 beep per 5 minutes.

I couldn't find any options on Google or get any useful sugestions from ChatGPT.
Is there a way to do this?
I don't mind hacky options and my phone has root access.

Thank you for sharing any thoughts on this

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. There's a related Q&A for a similar issue: [Delay notifications](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/88854/44325), let us know if the answer helps or not, thanks.

Comment: I think its a duplicate

Comment: Thanks for bringing this similar question up. From what I've gathered main suggestion there is to use Light Flow Pro, which has been abandoned for awhile and only works on much older versions of Android.